# Visual Studio Fonts and Colors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fonts, colors

[image]

In my visual studio, all the namespaces(cin,cout,endl) are coming in white color. I want to set all those in a different color

[image]

Another thing is how can I change the data type color and #include
for more convenience.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the color of **Display items** - **C++ variables** for changing cout/cin color and **C++ Function Templates** for endl color.

Please scroll down and check **Display items** more for details.

Comment: and also #include color,"text color" which is in cout<<"here will be different"<<endl; I am asking you lot's of question.. sorry for that.

Comment: Please change the Display items - "Keyword" color for changing data type color. Keep in mind that foreground color can't be changed for all.

Comment: Thanks for your help